# what can i do on my idea (about javascript html5 css)

Tags: javascript, html, editor

i want to make a demo using html css javascript, and the idea is :

1.i want to make a editor  liek a paper

2.you can write word on it like flash , the different from textarea is :
it can be writed on anywhere you clicked, and show the Cursor where you left click

3.it can be Paint simple Graphics like flash

so what can i do??

1.using div ?

2.using canvas ?

3.other

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use SVG/VML graphics.

Best way to do this is with a library such as [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [JSX Graph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/).

Hope you find what you want between these two libraries.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 could be done without Canvas. You could simply catch the click event on the underlying element, and create a div (with contenteditable) or a textarea (nicely styled), to that position.
For number 3 it would be handiest to use the Canvas element.

It also depends on what level of support you need to give to "older" browsers. As you might know Canvas is not supported in IE8 (and lower).

It also depends on whether you want to do something with the final result. Canvas is a canvas, and you can only export it as bitmap image, not vector. You might want to chose SVG to keep the image in a Vector format.